Why the Eigenvalues are discrete in the time independent Schrödinger equation?
Definition. The time independent Schrödinger equation is
$$\mathrm{H}\psi=E\psi$$ where $\mathrm{H}=-\frac{h^2}{2m}\partial_x^2+\frac{1}{2}mw^2X^2$
The boundary condition imposed on this equation is that $\psi$ and its
derivatives must decrease to 0 sufficiently rapidly as $x\to\pm\infty$, for example, by requiring that all the functional terms of the equation $\psi,
x^2\psi, \psi''$ be functions in $L^2(\mathbb{R})$, the Hilbert space of square-integrable complex-valued functions on the real line. This requirement forces the
eigenvalue $E$ to take on only certain restricted values, namely, values in
the discrete sequence
$$E_N=\left(N+\frac{1}{2}\right)\hbar{}w,\quad N\in \mathbb{N}_0$$
Reference.  P.L. Bowers, Lectures on Quantum Mechanics: A Primer for Mathematicians (Cambridge University Press, 2020).
Question. Why $E_N=\left(N+\frac{1}{2}\right)\hbar{}w$?.

What are you looking for? A textbook demonstration using ladder operators (which generate solutions spaced by $\hbar\omega$), or a textbook demonstration using series expansions (where the quantization arises so that the series terminates and the solution is normalizable), or something else?

I actually don't know. Is it possible to go from the equation $\mathrm{H}\psi = E \psi$ to $E = E_N$?

Yes, e.g. by either the ladder operators or series expansions.

Thanks. I am going to find with these keywords

See e.g. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quantum_harmonic_oscillator#Ladder_operator_method

See also: series method, operator method

Thank you for the references. I just understood the method of power series in  R.M. Eisberg, and R. Resnick, Quantum Physics of Atoms, Molecules, Solids, Nuclei, and Particles, 2. ed., 37. [Nachdr.] (Wiley, New York, 2009).  Now I will look for the ladder operators
